# mgo golang make a query with $and

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Here is my code  :

```
var cat string
var cat2 string
cat = "am"
cat2 = "bo"
var myarr = []string{cat,cat2}
err5 := c.Find(bson.M{"categories_data" : bson.M{"$in":myarr} }).All(&results)
```

So I would like to find all data that have am AND bo in the categories_data field wich is an array

Comment: You say you want `am AND bo`, but you seem to be describing `am OR bo`. Which do you really want? And what problem are you having?

Comment: i would like to have all object that have am & bo in their categories_data thanks

Comment: Is `categories_data` an array then?

Comment: yes it is it's an array